# Javascript get object key name

Tags: javascript

How would I get the key name for the follow? E.g I want "button1" and "button2"?

```
var buttons = {
    button1: {
        text: 'Close',
        onclick: function(){

        }
    },
    button2: {
        text: 'Close2',
        onclick: function(){

        }
    }
}

var i;
for(i in buttons){
    if(buttons.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        alert(buttons[i].text);
    }
}
```

I tried using `.push()` although this didn't work.

Comment: If your key names are actually `button1`, `button2` and so on, you might want to make `buttons` an array

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This might be better understood if you modified the wording up a bit:

```
var buttons = {
  foo: 'bar',
  fiz: 'buz'
};

for ( var property in buttons ) {
  console.log( property ); // Outputs: foo, fiz or fiz, foo
}
```

Note here that you're iterating over the properties of the object, using `property` as a reference to each during each subsequent cycle.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55wb2d34%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) says of `for ( variable in [object | array ] )` the following:

> Before each iteration of a loop, variable is assigned the next property name of object or the next element index of array. You can then use it in any of the statements inside the loop to reference the property of object or the element of array.

Note also that the property order of an object is not constant, and can change, unlike the index order of an array. That might come in handy.

Comment: how would you get foo?

Comment: @Demodave To get the value of the *foo* property, you would simply call it off the `buttons` object: `buttons.foo===buttons['foo']`. From within the for loop, you'd call `buttons[property]`. Today you can also use `Array.entries({foo:"bar",fizz:"buzz"})` to output `[['foo':'bar'],['fizz','buzz']]`.

Answer (score 75):

ECMAscript edition 5 also offers you the neat methods `Object.keys()` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

So

```
Object.keys( buttons );  // ['button1', 'button2'];
```

Comment: This gives all the keys as an array. How to get the key name of the specific key?

Comment: I am trying this: `Object.keys({myObj.fieldName})[0]`;

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Good premise, but you can't use an indexing expression as a short-hand assignment in an object

Answer (score 11):

Change `alert(buttons[i].text);` to `alert(i);`

Answer (score 8):

An ES6 update... though both filter and map might need customization.

`Object.entries(theObj)` returns a [[key, value],] array representation of an object that can be worked on using Javascript's array methods, .each(), .any(), .forEach(), .filter(), .map(), .reduce(), etc.

Saves a ton of work on iterating over parts of an object `Object.keys(theObj)`, or `Object.values()` separately.

```js
const buttons = {
    button1: {
        text: 'Close',
        onclick: function(){

        }
    },
    button2: {
        text: 'OK',
        onclick: function(){

        }
    },
    button3: {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onclick: function(){

        }
    }
}

list = Object.entries(buttons)
    .filter(([key, value]) => `${key}`[value] !== 'undefined' ) //has options
    .map(([key, value], idx) => `{${idx} {${key}: ${value}}}`)
    
console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 6):

Variable `i` is your looking key name.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example, it will help you to get object key name.

`var obj ={parts:{costPart:1000, salesPart: 2000}};
console.log(Object.keys(obj));`

the output would be **parts**.

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve key and value use the below.

```
 for (let property in buttons) {
    console.log('key:' + property, 'value:'+ buttons[property]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have access to Prototype, this could work. I wrote this code for myself just a few minutes ago; I only needed a single key at a time, so this isn't time efficient for big lists of key:value pairs or for spitting out multiple key names.

```
function key(int) {
    var j = -1;
    for(var i in this) {
        j++;
        if(j==int) {
            return i;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
Object.prototype.key = key;
```

This is numbered to work the same way that arrays do, to save headaches. In the case of your code:

```
buttons.key(0) // Should result in "button1"
```

Comment: Editing the prototypes is almost always a really bad idea.