# I need help generating header. using react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a table using objects right now my table generates the table rows but I also want it to generate the table header using the same object, right now the table header is being hard coded, if someone could help me with how to generate the table header inside the same object 'schoolData'.

```
//Rows

const schoolData = [
  { school : 'Middle School', year : '2017', date : '6/12/17', location : 
'Class',},
  { school : 'High School', year : '2017', date : '2/24/17', location : 
'Gym',},

];


export default class TableComplex extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs>
    <Tab label="School Type">
    <Table>
      <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn>School</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Year</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Location</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
        {schoolData.map( (row) => (
          <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.school}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.year}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.date}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.location}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </Tab>

  </Tabs>

);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object.keys on on the first element of school data and map TableHeaderColumn

```js
const schoolData = [
  { school : 'Middle School', year : '2017', date : '6/12/17', location : 
'Class',},
  { school : 'High School', year : '2017', date : '2/24/17', location : 
'Gym',},

];

// declare this in render method
const headers = Object.keys(schoolData[0]).map(header => 
    <TableHeaderColumn>{header}</TableHeaderColumn>);
    
// put it in your react component
<TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
  <TableRow>
    { headers }
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>

// for TableRows
const rows = (row) => Object.keys(row).map(r => 
    <TableRowColumn>{row[r]}</TableRowColumn>);

<TableRow>
  {rows(row)}
</TableRow>
```

Comment: so if i wanted to do the same thing for rows would i just do Object.keys(schoolData[1]) insted of 0?

Comment: No you don't, using that would yield the same results as you are getting the keys and not the values of the elements in schoolData. Note that both have similar keys.

Comment: so how would i do it for the row?

Comment: but how is it going to know where to pull the data from? what if i have multiple objects how will it know where to pull the data for that specific table row?

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I implemented rows as a function now so that you can pass in row at each iteration of schoolData

Comment: but instead of passing it at each iteration how can I pass it once and it will generate all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your [object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10334267/1580610)

```
for ( property in schoolData[0] ) { console.log( property ); }
```