# Access Outer Name of object literal two item array

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I can access the inner properties, but cant seem to figure out how to access the name of the set. For example, in the following code I can get the values of planet earth but I cant see to figure out how to display the name earth

```
var planet = {
  Earth: [
    'water',
    'rock'
  ]
};

alert(**output Key/Earth ** + " consists of " planet.Earth[0] + " & " + planet.Earth[1]);
```

I've tried this as well. I can get type and location but not the planet itself such as "Earth" or "Venus" to be displayed. I either get [undefined] or [object object]

```
var planets = {
    "Earth": {type: "Terrestrial ", location: "Milky Way"},
    "Venus": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"}
};

alert("Planet: " + planets[0] + " TYPE: " + planets.Earth.type + "LOCATION: " + planets.Earth.location);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get object key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334267/javascript-get-object-key-name)

Comment: `Object.keys(planets)[0]`  ??

Comment: This totally worked! Object.keys(planets)[0] Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through object keys using `for(var key in obj)` pattern, like this:

```js
var planet = {
   Earth: [
     'water',
     'rock'
   ]
};
        
for(var key in planet) {
  console.log(key)
}
```

Or with your second example:

```js
var planets = {
  "Earth": {type: "Terrestrial ", location: "Milky Way"},
  "Venus": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"}
};

for(var key in planets) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Commercial Suicide 
I found your response  quite useful as I will need to iterate through them as sets. Cheers!

Comment: @loganpixel, nice to hear, that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help and guidance from all respondents, each was beneficial in helping me to understand this problem. I selected the following from @Commercial Suicide as my answer as the code was succinct and enabled me a way to iterate through them. I can now continue to access my planets and their various properties.

In Regards to duplicate: I didn't see the answer on the other page as a duplicate right away. many of the top answers were about getting foo or fizz properties and not the key. I see now buried further down in those answers someone did provide the answer "ECMAscript edition 5 also offers you the neat methods Object.keys()" [Javascript get object key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334267/javascript-get-object-key-name)

Cheers!

```js
var planets = {
  "Earth": {type: "Terrestrial ", location: "Milky Way"},
  "Venus": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"}
};


//expanded for loop //
for(var key in planets) {
console.log("PLANET: " + key + " TYPE: " + planets.Earth.type + "LOCATION: " + planets.Earth.location);
}
```

UPDATE!!   Here is a fiddle that shows the above as well as getting values from the inner object.

```
var moviesNested = {
  Morag: {
    Movie: 'Guardians..Galaxy ',
    Hero: "Star Lord"
  },
  Tatooine: {
    Movie: 'Star Wars',
    Hero: "Skywalker"
  }
};

function showMovieData(movieSet) {

 for (var property in movieSet) {

  //outer property ------------------------------------
  console.log(property); 

  //inner as keys ---------------------------------
  for (var key in movieSet[property])

  console.log(key); //hero & movie
  console.log(movieSet[property].Movie);
  console.log(movieSet[property].Hero);

  var fullString = "<p>" + property + " <br /> " +
  movieSet[property].Movie + "<br /> " +
  movieSet[property].Hero;

  document.getElementById("outJS").innerHTML += fullString;
  //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "Loop: " + i + "<br>"; 
  }
}

showMovieData(moviesNested);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/carvingpixel/86rfvp8d/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.enteries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). It returns an array from object.

```js
var planets = {
    "Earth": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"},
    "Venus": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"}
};
var arr = Object.entries(planets);
arr.forEach((obj) => {
console.log("Planet: " + obj[0] + " TYPE: " + obj[1].type + " LOCATION: " + obj[1].location);
});
```

You can also use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var planets = {
    "Earth": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"},
    "Venus": {type: "Terrestrial", location: "Milky Way"}
};
Object.keys(planets).forEach((key) => {
console.log("Planet: " + key + " TYPE: " + planets[key].type + " LOCATION: " + planets[key].location);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Hassan Imam. The snippet worked great here on the site but in my IDE I get highlighted warning and nothing happens. "Expression statement is not assignment or call". I checked the link you provided regarding Object.entries as well but had no success with it. "Unresolved function or method entries()" trying to use that page example of console.log(Object.entries(obj));

Comment: Yes, it's an experimental feature hasn't been standardised yet. I have updated the solutions using `Object.keys`