# get the name of the key, in array of objects - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array for  instance

```
humans:[
  dave: {
   ...daveData
  },
  mike: { 
   ...mikeData
  }
]
```

now calling `human[0]` returns `{..daveData}` but how can I get the **NAME** of the KEY meaning `'dave'`, `'mike'` as a string ... sorry if I'm repeating myself, but I didn't find similar questions.

Also to say im using React to  render

tags using array.map()

Comment: That's invalid data.

Comment: Hi there, the code example you provided is *not* valid JavaScript format. Can you provide working code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get object key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334267/javascript-get-object-key-name)

Comment: I'm pulling the data from Firebase ... firebase creates for me an array of objects, each object has some "-L4eimbEHuoYMpmkGVTs" random Id ... and i need  this  ID as a string

Comment: **Did you mean:** `{humans:[{dave: {...}}, {mike: { ... }}]}` or `[{dave: {...}}, {mike: { ... }}]`??

Comment: yes my mistake sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your array is invalid, assuming from the comments your array is like this:

```
const humans = [
  {
   dave: 'bar' // or whatever, doesn't need to be a string
  },
  {
   mike: 'baz'
  }
];
```

then you could:

```js
const humans = [
  {
   dave: 'bar'
  },
  {
   mike: 'baz'
  }
];

const myKeys = humans.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);

console.log(myKeys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function and `spread operator`.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var data = [{dave: {}}, {mike: {}}, {'Георги': {}}, {'Димитранов': {}}];

var results = data.reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...Object.keys(c)], []);

console.log(results);
```

## Resources

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Spread operator (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)